# How to apply a function to a list of matrices elementwise

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

I have a list of matrices and I would like to multiply each matrix with a different factor from a vector of the same length as the list.
I tried the following:

```
lapply(list(mat1, mat2, mat3),"*",c(1,2,3))
```

However, this returns:

```
list(mat1*c(1,2,3), mat2*c(1,2,3), mat3*c(1,2,3))
```

instead of what I need:

```
list(mat1*1,mat2*2,mat3*3)
```

Has anybody a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please add your data objects to your question (`dput(mat1)`, `dput(mat2)`, ... ).

Comment: Possibly with mapply? Something like `mapply(function(x, y) x * y, lst, vec)`? (not tested... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As docendo discimus suggested you can use `mapply`

```
 l <- list(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2), matrix(5:8, ncol = 2), matrix(9:12, ncol = 2))
 v <- 1:3
 mapply(function(x,y) x*y, x = l, y = v, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Or just use `Map`

```
Map("*", l, v)
```

Comment: second solution is even much faster

Comment: You have the choice! ;-)